# Which compound is more reactive towards acetylation, 4-aminophenol or 4-aminocyclohexanol?

Tags: organic-chemistry

Does the delocalisation of the lone pair of electrons in the NH2 group mean that they are less available to attack the carbon making the 4-aminocyclohexanol more reactive? Or does the polarisation of the neighbouring molecule due to the higher electron density of the benzene ring make the 4-aminophenol more reactive?

Comment: [*p*-Anisidine](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-Anisidine) and [DMAP](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/4-Dimethylaminopyridine) are especially nucleophilic specifically because of the resonance caused by situations like what you describe. That's also why they're so toxic. Not an answer, but certainly related.

Answer (score 1):

4-aminocyclohexanol should be more reactive towards acetylation because the reactivity depends on the availability of the lone pair on N to be able to attack the C atom during acetylation. Since in 4-aminophenol the lone pair resonates in the benzene ring, its availability to attack will get reduced making it lesser reactive towards acetylation.